# Can be possible substitute to a mysql event with a mysql trigger or a cronjob?

Tags: mysql

I tried to run scheduled events on 3 different free host database without success. This function is disabled. So I want to know if is possible to "convert" a scheduled event like this:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT update_status ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND STARTS '2019-11-22 01:39:34' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE users AS t 
SET t.online=IF(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(
t.lastact, DATE_ADD(NOW(),
INTERVAL -15 MINUTE)))>=0,1,0)
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

into a trigger with the same effect.

Comment: Which "effect"? It looks like this event wouldn't work. What is `t` in `t.online`?

Comment: On local server it works perfectly. `t` is the users's table parameter. I call `t.online` instead of `users.online`

Comment: Ah.. I missed the UPDATE keyword. Not used to scroll code horizontally :-)

Comment: There is actually no need for that event. You can calculate the `online` value "on the fly" when you need it.

Comment: I looked a lot for a solution that works when user close the browser and actually this is the only one that works as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for that event. If you want to know if a specific user is online, you can run this query:

```
select u.lastact <= now() - interval 15 minute as online
from users as u
```

If you want to get all users, which are online right now (have been active within the last 15 miutes):

```
select u.*
from users as u
where u.lastact > now() - interval 15 minute
```